# What is the space and time complexity for this function that gets a node in a linked list based on its position from the tail?

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, singly-linked-list

**What is the space and time complexity (worst-case) for the following solution?**

```
Node getNodeFromTail(Node head, int x){
    Node p = head;
    Node q = head;

    int diff = 0;

    while (p.next != NULL){
        p = p.next;

        if (diff >= x)
            q = q.next;
        else
            diff++;
    }
    return q;
}
```

This is the explanation of the code above:
Take this linked list for example: 1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5

x == value from tail,
when x is 0, the result should be 5
when x is 1, the result should be 4
when x is 2, the result should be 3 and so on.

This is what I think:
**Space Complexity**
Constant space O(1)

**Time Complexity**
The while loop walks through the linked list in **O(n) time**;
where n = the length of the linked list.

However, I think there is an extra complexity because of the *if statement*, which I feel should be **O(n-x) time**
Thus leaving us with: **O(n) * O(n-x)** which is almost an overall time complexity of **O(n^2) (i.e. quadratic)**.
I just have a feeling that this is not exactly linear time in the worst case.
Is this correct?

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31190255/12357170

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity is O(n) or linear. The condition of the while loop depends only on the p = p->next instruction inside the loop. The other instructions inside the loop are executed in constant time, and don't have impact on the condition of the while loop. So, we can conclude that loop is executed exactly n times ( if list is n elements long).
Also note that there is no other loop inside first while loop, like you are suggesting in your question.